# Replace until a pattern is found in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have been trying to transform the following string:

```
CN=John Doe,OU=IT,OU=Support,OU=Department,OU=HQ,DC=FR,DC=CONTOSO,DC=COM
```

to:

```
FR.CONTOSO.COM
```

As a first step, I tried to remove everything until ",DC" pattern.

I thought I could use the un-greedy ".+?" to match everything until the first ",DC" pattern:

```
$str = 'CN=John Doe,OU=IT,OU=Support,OU=Department,OU=HQ,DC=FR,DC=CONTOSO,DC=COM'
$str -replace '.+?,DC', ''
```

This returns:

```
=COM
```

Any idea why it's getting only the last one even with the un-greedy version?
How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just split the string:

```
$parts = ('CN=John Doe,OU=IT,OU=Support,OU=Department,OU=HQ,DC=FR,DC=CONTOSO,DC=COM' -split ',')
$newString = '{0}.{1}.{2}' -f $parts[-3].split('=')[1], $parts[-2].split('=')[1], $parts[-1].split('=')[1]
```

Comment: I feel like there should be an AD-string type that makes this easier.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Sounds like a great project for you :)

Comment: Check it out. This isn't the first time I've needed this done so it's not time wasted I tell myself

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I took @EBGreen's advice and decided to make a function that does all the work:

```
#Requires -Version 4
Function ConvertFrom-DistinguishedName
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType('System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory)]
        [Alias('DistinguishedName', 'Name')]
        [ValidatePattern('^CN=.+?,(OU=.+?,)+DC=.+$')]
        [string]
        $Path
    )
    $local:ErrorActionPreference = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Stop
    $WS = $Path -split ',' # working set

    $User = $WS[0] -replace 'CN='
    $Domain = $WS.Where({$PSItem.StartsWith('DC=')}).ToLower() -replace 'dc=' -join '.'
    $OU = $WS.Where({$PSItem.StartsWith('OU=')}) -replace 'OU='
    [array]::Reverse($OU)

    [pscustomobject]@{
        'User'   = $User
        'Domain' = $Domain
        'OU'     = $OU -join '\'
    }
}

PS C:\> ConvertFrom-DistinguishedName 'CN=John Doe,OU=IT,OU=Support,OU=Department,OU=HQ,DC=FR,DC=CONTOSO,DC=COM'

User     Domain         OU
----     ------         --
John Doe fr.contoso.com HQ\Department\Support\IT
```

The end result?  This converts your distinguished AD name to a PSCustomObject you can easily work with.

Answer (score 1):

To get the domain out of the Distinguishedname, you will want to use `-Split`. Finally we can use `-join` to insert '.' between the DCs

This will store your domain string to `$domain`:

```
$dn = "CN=John Doe,OU=IT,OU=Support,OU=Department,OU=HQ,DC=FR,DC=CONTOSO,DC=COM"
$domain = $dn -Split "," | ? {$_ -like "DC=*"}
$domain = $domain -join "." -replace ("DC=", "")

Write-Host "Current Domain: " $domain
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the ^ to start from the beginning.

```
$str = 'CN=John Doe,OU=IT,OU=Support,OU=Department,OU=HQ,DC=FR,DC=CONTOSO,DC=COM'
$str = $str -replace '^.+?,DC',''
$str = $str -replace 'DC=',''
$str -replace ',','.'
```

Comment: You can shorten this to `$str -replace "^.*?,DC=" -replace ",DC=", "."`

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody bothered explaining the behavior yet:

The replacement operation replaces *every* occurrence of the pattern `.+?,DC` in the string, so it first removes `CN=John Doe,OU=IT,OU=Support,OU=Department,OU=HQ,DC`, then continues where that replacement left off and removes `=FR,DC`, and then `=CONTOSO,DC`, leaving you with just `=COM`.

To avoid this behavior you need to anchor the expression at the beginning of the string (`^`), as others have already suggested. The second replacement for substituting the remaining `,DC=` with dots can be daisy-chained to the first one, so you need just one statement:

```
$str -replace '^.*?,dc=' -replace ',dc=', '.'
```